# can't get pyinstaller hooks to work with gdal

Tags: python, gdal, pyinstaller, osgeo

I have a python script which I would like to package with pyinstaller. It uses osgeo.ogr and osgeo.osr. Using the basic build command (`python pyinstaller.py --onefile c:\path\to\my\file.py`) it creates the spec file and the exe. When I run the exe, I get the following error:

```
File "c:\Programming\Python\pyinstaller-2.0\PyInstaller\loader\iu.py", line 409, in importHook
raise ImportError("No module named %s" % fqname)
ImportError: No module named _gdal
```

`_gdal` is found in the osgeo package (I can import it using `import osgeo._gdal`). I have tried creating a hook for it (tried `hook-_gdal.py`,`hook-osgeo._gdal.py`,`hook-_gdal.osgeo.py`), with the single line `hiddenimports = ['osgeo._gdal']` (also tried `hiddenimports = ['_gdal']`). Whenever I add the path to the spec file as `hookspath='c:\\Programming\\Python\\pyinstaller-2.0\hooks'`, I get the following error when I try to build it (regardless of what's in the directory):

```
File "c:\Programming\Python\pyinstaller-2.0\PyInstaller\hooks\hook-site.py", line 37, in hook
new_code_object = PyInstaller.utils.misc.get_code_object(fake_file)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'utils'
```

Clearly I'm making a number of errors here, but I can't figure out where. Can anyone help?

Comment: Just to be clear, the script runs perfectly when I run it with the python interpreter - no complaints about `_gdal`

Comment: It seems that it's actually a problem with the environment (which I haven't quite figured out yet). The executable was built in the OSGeo4W Python installation, and running it from the OSGeo4W shell failed with the above error. When I ran it from a regular `cmd` prompt, it worked fine (just make sure to set the `GDAL_DATA` environment variable correctly).

Comment: Any update on this issue? Was it just an environment issue?  Maybe a pyinstaller update has fixed it?

Comment: I think the problem wasn't with pyinstaller but the fact that I was doing it from the OSGeo4W shell. It was a while ago now, but if I recall I think I just ran pyinstaller from my regular shell and it built fine.

Comment: Thanks, just curious!

Comment: @rudivonstaden how do we make sure that gdal environment variable is set correctly from pyinstaller?